# How to use SQL to extract highest sales amount generated by a customer on their last transaction date?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to determine the highest sales amount for a single purchase generated by a customer on their last transaction date.

I tried using the max feature on both the order date and the sales amount however the results will show all the purchases a customer made on that date instead of just the one transaction associated with the highest sales amount. This in turns gives me multiple customer keys for just one customer as shown by the image attached. Below is the code I used.

```
SELECT DISTINCT D.CustomerKey 'Customer Key',C.[OrderDate] 'Order Date', 
MAX(C.salesamount) 'Max Sales Amount'
FROM [dbo].[FactInternetSales] C 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[DimCustomer] 
D ON C.CustomerKey = D.CustomerKey 
WHERE C.[OrderDate]=
(SELECT max(C.orderdate) FROM [dbo[FactInternetSales] C 
WHERE D.CustomerKey = C.CustomerKey) 
GROUP BY D.customerkey,C.salesamount, C.OrderDate 
ORDER BY D.customerkey
```

I expect the results to show three columns: the customer key - but only one for each customer, the order date for their last purchase and the highest sales amount for that date.

Comment: Do you have some sample data and the expected outcome of that data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few points, `GROUP BY` will give you a distinct combination so no need to add distinct explicitly also you don't have to group by sales amount. The modified below query will give the max sales amount on each day the customer made a purchase.

```
SELECT D.CustomerKey 'Customer Key',C.[OrderDate] 'Order Date', 
MAX(C.salesamount) 'Max Sales Amount'
FROM [dbo].[FactInternetSales] C 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[DimCustomer] 
D ON C.CustomerKey = D.CustomerKey 
WHERE C.[OrderDate]=
(SELECT max(C.orderdate) FROM [dbo[FactInternetSales] C 
WHERE D.CustomerKey = C.CustomerKey) 
GROUP BY D.customerkey, C.OrderDate 
Order by D.CustomerKey
```